# \newcommand named \endomorphism does not work

Tags: macros

I want to define a new command via `\newcommand{\endomorphism}[1]{\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)}`, but this does not work since a latex error tells me "Command `\endomorphism` already defined" (see MWE below). When I try `\renewcommand{\endomorphism}[1]{\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)}` the error "Command `\endomorphism` undefined" is returned.

As a workaround I found that using the command name with a capital "e", i.e. `\Endomorphism`, works (again, see MWE). However, this is not desired.

What is the problem here? Can I somehow resolve it? I figured something might be clashing with the standard command `\end` but I am not proficient enough to figure that out myself :(. Thx.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\endomorphism}[1]{\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)}
%\renewcommand{\endomorphism}[1]{\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\Endomorphism}[1]{\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}
Let $\endomorphism{V} = \{\textrm{this does not work}\}$ and $\Endomorphism{V} = \{\textrm{linear mapping from $V$ to $V$}\}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The error-message is: `! LaTeX Error: Command \endomorphism already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` The 2nd sentence is important. ;-) With a recent tex-distribution you can do `\NewDocumentCommand{\endomorphism}{m}{\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)}`.

Comment: On my system the following hack works: `\newcommand{{{{ \endomorphism}}}}[1]{\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)}` (There must be a space between the 4-th curly opening brace and `\endomorphism`. ;-)

Comment: Currently (August 2022) you cannot apply `\newcommand` but you can apply `\renewcommand` to commands whose name is "illegal". So how about: `\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{endomorphism}{\def\endomorphism{}\csname @firstoftwo\endcsname\renewcommand}{}\newcommand{\endomorphism}[1]{\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)}`

Comment: Would it be better to make the other question a duplicate of this one?  This one has a MWE, and that one is using `\input{settings.tex}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not allowed to define a command whose name begins by `\end` because those names are used in the internal coding of the environments (when you define an environment `foo`, two commands are created : `\foo` and `\endfoo`).

However, if you actually want to define the command `\endomorphism`, you can by using the TeX command `\def` (the concept of environment is a concept of LaTeX and raw TeX knows nothing about environment and that's why `\def` does not forbide `\endomorphism` (of course, you should not define an environment called `{omorphism}`)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\endomorphism#1{\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}
Let $\endomorphism{V} = ...$
\end{document}
```

---

*Remark*

Defining a command whose output is `\mathrm{End}\left(#1\right)` is not recommended because the systematic use of `\left(` and `\right)` is discouraged: you will have extra small horizontal spaces on both sides of the parentheses... Many people recommend to only use `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: If you go this route, it might be wise to leave a comment in your code about why you're not using `\newcommand`.  Otherwise, you might come back to this in a few months and "clean up the source file" and end up back where you started. 
(small typo: raw TeX knows *nothing* about environment)

Comment: @Teepeemm: You are right.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply and provided understanding of the situation. And also thanks for the additional remark!

Comment: `\newenvironment` is not needed for defining environments. If this was the case, "illegalizing" `\end..`-macros was not necessary as an environment's `\end..`-macro would be defined in any case and `\newcommand`'s/`\newenvironment`'s checking whether commands are already defined would be sufficient for catching up the situation. But if defining a command `\endfoo` and some time afterwards only defining a macro `\foo`  "by hand" for future invocation via `\begin`-macro, then the carrying-out of the command `\endfoo` at the end of the `foo`-environment might form some kind of undesired behavior.